# react-beautiful-dnd re-loads iframe within draggable, is there a way to stop this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using `react-beautiful-dnd` to drag and drop different parts of my application.

Some parts however use an iframe with a third party application widget in.

When I drag these they re-render the entire iframe which I don't want to happen, is there a way to stop this?

See example of this happening.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-ganguly-n11sc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't have a solution but I was trying your code. Some properties of dropped component changes causing a re-render of the dropped component which reload the iframe.  I was trying to wrap your component with iframe in `React.memo()` so it won't re-render if the props are the same. You may try it yourself. https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-jennings-uiuiv?file=/src/Iframe.js It's stopped dropping with my code move.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried doing the same, and tried using shouldComponentUpdate with class based component, I got it to stop re-rendering within the same column, but as soon as it moves column it re-renders.  I guess because it's now part of a different list.  I am unsure of if there  will be a way around this...